# Experimental design - hyperparameter optimization

Tags: neural-network, hyperparameter

I'm reading a paper by [Bergstra and Bengio (2012)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf) on random search for hyperparameter optimization. I'm confused by their graph and explanation in Section 2.2:

"Figure 2 illustrates the results of a random experiment: an experiment of 256 trials training neural networks to classify the rectangles data set. Since the trials of a random experiment are i.i.d., a random search experiment involving $S$ i.i.d. trials can also be interpreted as N independent experiments of $s$ trials, as long as $sN \le S$."

That part I think I understand. Here's my take on it:

If I draw from a uniform(0, 1) random variable 100 times, then I have 100 i,.i.d. samples. That's the same as if I had drawn 10 times each from 10 separate uniform(0, 1) random variables.

In their figure (below), they say they had 256 trials. I *think* they chose 256 possible values of a hyperparameter and trained a neural network for each value.

[image]

In the caption for the figure, they say they had "256 trials of a random experiment...optimizing a neural network....At horizontal axis position 8, we consider 256 trials to be 32 experiments of 8 trials each".

This implies that at horizontal axis position 1, they would have 1 experiment of 256 trials.

My question is: did they train those 256 models and then break up the results into smaller chunks? Like this:

Experiment 1: $[\lambda^1, \ldots, \lambda^{256}]$

Experiment 2: $[\lambda^1, \ldots, \lambda^{128}], [\lambda^{129}, \ldots, \lambda^{256}]$

...

with value $\lambda^{129}$ from Experiment 1 equal to value $\lambda^{129}$ in Experiment 2?

Or did they do something else?